# How can I count the number of occurrences of a range of values in one column, against all unique values in another, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, multiple-columns

I have a table with any number of duplicates in the brand column, with a limited number of options in the size column:

```
Item    Brand           Size
1       BiGNRG          AA
2       LongLife        AAA
3       LongLife        AAA
4       BiGNRG          AA
5       LongLife        D
6       EcoBatt         C
7       BiGNRG          AAA
8       BiGNRG          AA
9       EcoBatt         C
```

I need an SQL query to convert that information to this:

```
Brand    AA     AAA     C       D
BiGNRG   3      1       0       0
EcoBatt  0      0       2       0
LongLife 0      2       0       1
```

I cannot figure out how to convert this data into this format.

Comment: Is it always going to be 4 distinct sizes or do you want the number of columns to be dynamic?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the number of the option is limited you could try using an group by un select union  all

```
select brand, count(AA) AA, count(AAA)  AAA, count(C) C, count(D) D 
from (
    select  Brand, 'AA' AA ,  NULL  AAA,  NULL C , NULL D 
    from my_table 
    where size ='AA'
    union ALL 
    select  Brand, null ,  'AAA'  ,  NULL , NULL
    from my_table 
    where size ='AAA'
    union ALL 
    select  Brand, null ,  null   ,  'C' , NULL
    from my_table 
    where size ='C'
    union ALL 
    select  Brand, null ,  null   , null,  'D'
    from my_table 
    where size ='D'
) T 
group by brand
```